# how to send readstream as response

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest, httpresponse, filestream

when i try to send read stream as response i am getting error

```
    var http = require('http'),
        fileSystem = require('fs'),
        path = require('path');

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3');
        var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
        });

        var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);

response.send(readStream)
    })
    .listen(2000);
```

i want to send as response.send(readStream) not as readStream.pipe(response);
is there is any possibility  to send like this ?

Comment: What's the issue with using `.pipe()`?

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP response object in node (`response` in the code above) is a writable stream. This means if we have a readable stream that represents the content of `myfile.mp3`, you can just pipe the content of the file into the response object. This would look something like this:

`readStream.pipe(response)`

This prevents the file (i.e. `myfile.mp3`) being loaded completely into memory before sending it as a response, and is the suggested way to do so in order to prevent high memory pressure on the server side.

**Is there any possibility to send files without using `pipe()`?**

Actually there is a method which allows to send files without using `pipe()`, but this approach is discouraged as it first loads the whole file into memory and after that writes the file to the response object. Anyways, here is an example on how to do it:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3');
    var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.end(data);
    });
}).listen(2000);
```

Comment: You can also use `.on('data', ...).on('end', ...)` to stream without using `.pipe()` (although I don't see the point of doing it like that).

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you really want, then you could do it like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fileSystem = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3');
    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg' });
    readStream.on('data', data => response.send(data));
    readStream.on('close', () => response.end());
})
.listen(2000);
```

Otherwise readStream.pipe(response):

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3');
    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
    readStream.pipe(response);
})
.listen(2000);
```